# Django ORM split the name and search

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a model named Suburb. with one field called name.

name of the suburb can be mulitple words say "East west country". I want all the records whose part words starts with given string.

```
class Suburb(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('suburb name'), blank=False, max_length=200)

search_string = "we"

# Give me all records whose part words starts with "search_string"

Suburb.objects.filter(...) # with ignore case ??? 

Example 
----------
1) "East west one"
2) "We east two"
3) "North south three"

result should be 1) and 2)
```

I have a pythonic solution. but its performance is quite bad.

DB = MYSQL

Thanks in advance

Comment: Doing this in your database is always going to be inefficient. You should consider using a search engine like Elasticsearch, which is designed for this purpose.

Comment: unfortunately i cant at this point. i have to fix it in the current structure. I agree with you

Comment: what db type are you using

Comment: We have mysql in our setup

Comment: You may consider issuing raw sql queries with Suburb.objects.raw("...")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best Django solution without engaging [Full Text Search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) or search engine would be to use [icontains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#icontains)

So in your case

```
Suburb.objects.filter(name__icontains=search_string)
```

**Edit**:  for start of each word use iregex:

For mysql `[[:<:]]` signifies start of word

So something like this would be solution

```
Suburb.objects.filter.(name__iregex=r'[[:<:]]' + re.escape(search_string)
```

Also note that following solution doesn't scale as there is wildcard regex

Comment: This could potentially solve my issue. There is another part to it. What if i had to find the records which exactly match the part words. I mean "west" in this case . Any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean with "match the part words"

Comment: i mean if  records have  "East west south" , "East we south", "north south west", "we are" etc. I would need all records which match complete part words. Say in this case "East west south", "north south west" only. As substrings/part words completely match

Comment: If i understood correctly you want to find whole word from start to end that would be regex  r'[[:<:]]' + re.escape(search_string) +  r'[[:>:]]'

Comment: Thanks mate. you saved my day. was fixing a huge performance issue and was in pressure

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`istartswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#istartswith) and [`icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) with the [`Q` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

```
search_string = 'we'
Sample.objects.filter(Q(name__istartswith=search_string) | Q(name__icontains=' ' + search_string))
```

With this solution I am assuming that your words are always delimited by a space character.

Using the [`iregex`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#iregex) filter as another option which could be used but I have not created an example for.

Answer (score 0):

Search by part word:

```
search_string = "we"
Suburb.objects.filter(name__icontains = search_string)
    Result:
    1) "East west one"
    2) "We east two"
```

Search from starting word:

```
search_string = "we"
Suburb.objects.filter(name__startswith = search_string)
    Result:
    2) "We east two"
```

Search exact work:

```
search_string = "we"
Suburb.objects.filter(name__iexact = search_string)
Result: no result
search_string = "We east two"
Result:
2) "We east two"
```

Comment: Nah, doesnt work. specially i want part words/substrings . it will give me result anything in the string.